# Does a title returned by the Wikipedia API always represent the URL suffix of that page?

Tags: wikipedia, wikipedia-api

The Wikipedia API by default returns a title for a page (at least for links), e.g. "title": "Amazon River".

Does a title always unambiguously translate into the URL, i.e. replacing " " with "_" and adding the prefix, e.g. en.wikipedia.org/wiki/, resulting in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_River?

Is there a problem with non-standard characters?

How can I additionally ask for the pages' URLs?

Comment: In case you haven't seen it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:URLs

Comment: @ jbaums: Thanks for the link - but that doesn't explicitly answer the question, right?

Comment: @Termininja: An API response containing a link to the C# page ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_(programming_language) ) identifies it as `"title": "C Sharp (programming language)"`, so that doesn't seem to be a problem - but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @G.L.Merebet - not directly, which is why I posted as a comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the title always matches the URL, i.e. can unambiguously be translated into the URL.

However, to be absolutely sure to get the valid URL and to avoid the translation, one can use `prop=info&inprop=url` to request the URL with special characters being percent encoded.

An Example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&redirects&generator=links&prop=info&inprop=url&gpllimit=20&titles=Dolphin